# [ros2run]: Process exited with failure 3221226505

Tags: windows

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No clue what this error code means.

System:
Windows 10
ROS Humble

Github repo with my code (forked from robosavvy's vive_ros):
https://github.com/NU-Haptics-Lab/open_vr_ros/tree/ros2

I've tried setting my ROS_DOMAIN_ID and nothing changes.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/416479/%5Bros2run%5D:-process-exited-with-failure-3221226505/) by [buckley.toby](https://answers.ros.org/users/30452/buckley.toby/) on ROS Answers with karma: 116 on 2023-06-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [buckley.toby](https://answers.ros.org/users/30452/buckley.toby/) on 2023-06-27**:
just a note to anyone reading this in the future: that failure code is a generic Windows failure code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I figured it out:

Since I was porting the code from ROS1, they initiated their node like this:

```
class OPEN_VRnode
{
  public:
    OPEN_VRnode(int rate);
    ~OPEN_VRnode();
    bool Init();
    void Run();
    void Shutdown();
    bool setOriginCB(const std::shared_ptr<std_srvs::srv::Empty::Request> req, std::shared_ptr<std_srvs::srv::Empty::Response> res);
    void set_feedback(const sensor_msgs::msg::JoyFeedback::ConstPtr msg);
    rclcpp::Node:: nh_;
    VRInterface vr_;
```

...

```
OPEN_VRnode::OPEN_VRnode(int rate)
  : loop_rate_(rate)
  , nh_("open_vr_node")
  , vr_()
  , world_offset_({0, 0, 0})
  , world_yaw_(0)
{
```

But this resulted in no `shared_ptr` being created, so then later in the code when I ran `rclcpp::spin_some(nh_.get_shared_from_this());` there was no valid shared ptr to pass to spin_some.

Fixed the issue by changing `nh_` to `nh_ptr_` and the type from `rclcpp::Node` to `rclcpp::Node::SharedPtr` and then initializing it in the class constructor.

Full code can be found on my repository:
https://github.com/NU-Haptics-Lab/open_vr_ros/tree/ros2

---

Originally posted by [buckley.toby](https://answers.ros.org/users/30452/buckley.toby/) with karma: 116 on 2023-06-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0